# TCP Ack-Fin after Ack-Push

Tags: tcp

In a tcp/ip connexion, when the server replies ack-Fin to ack-push, what does it means ?
The client try to send 1024 bytes. Does it mean that the server refuses the push ?

Comment: ack-fin sounds like fin+ack, but what is ack-push?

Answer (score 0):

No.  The `FIN` just means that the application on that side closed the socket (or exited, causing the socket to be closed).

Comment: No. The `FIN` just means that the application has stopped _sending_ data. According to the TCP specification, it can still listen (and acknowledge). Most applications don't use half-open sockets, however.